# Excel: SUMIF Based on Two Other Columns Matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I've been attempting to find an answer on this but have not yet found something that specifically helps.

Situation:

I have two worksheets in an Excel file. In one worksheet, Worksheet: All, I have a list of every unique campaign advertisement put out by candidates during an election year. Column D has the name of the candidate who put out the ad, and column H has the total air time the ad played during the election:

[Image of Worksheet: All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iCib.png)

[image]

In another worksheet, Worksheet: Governors, I have a list of each governor candidate in column D:

[Image of Worksheet: Governor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPgtn.png)

[image]

My goal is to sum up in column G the values in All!H for each candidate to get a total amount of airtime the candidate had. So, basically, I need to sum up every value of All!H for which All!D:D = Governor!D:D.

I attempt to put that into a SUMIF function:

```
=SUMIF(All!H:H,D:D=All!D:D)
```

but that gets me a 0 when I should be getting, for David Williams at least, 18360.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that *David Williams* is in Governor!D2 then put this in Governor!G2

```
=sumifs('all'!h:h, 'all'!d:d, d2)
```

Fill down as necessary to collect total airtime for the other names.

Note that SUMIF and SUMIFS have slightly different syntax. I've supplied the correct formula for a SUMIFS in case you want to add additional criteria. Your original should have been,

```
=sumif('all'!d:d, d2, 'all'!h:h)
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked, and your SUMIFS is working on some other things I needed summed with additional criteria (specifying air time for ads coded attack, uncivil, etc.).